How do I increase element searching attempts interval in Ranorex Studio?
While performing a test Ranorex takes multiple attempts to find demanded item, withing a search timeout. I need to take control on the interval between these attempts.
I've checked all of the project settings, but didn't find anything related. Is there any way to edit this interval?

In Ranorex, you can adjust the frequency of retrying to find an item by changing the "Retry Interval" in the vault settings. This parameter controls the timeout between each retry during the search timeout.

Thanks for your answer, but could you be more specific please. What is "vault settings"? Where do i find it? Would be nice if you'll give me stepwise instructions.
